# Bug with image slider

Tags: javascript

My company had a website created by a design agency. They use a custom CMS, which makes it very difficult to get into the raw code of the site. I've been trying to catch a particular bug with our image slider.

http://informedfamilies.org/

When you click on the navigation buttons in the slider ("1,2,3,4,5"), the slide switches to the appropriate image, but only the first time. If you click another button a second time, the slider doesn't change. The shadow below the image seems to get darker, so I'm assuming the images are simply not going away, and simply stacking under the main image.

Any help fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

```
$('#home_features .listeditem').wrapAll('<div id="fade" />');
$('#fade').css('background', 'transparent');

var featureCt = $('#fade .listeditem').length;
if (featureCt > 1) {
    $('#home_features').each(function() {
        var controlDiv = $('<div />').attr('id', 'switcher');
        for (var i = 1; i <= featureCt; i++) {
            var control = $('<a href="#" class="selector" id="s' + i + '">' + i + '</a>');
            if (i == 1) control.addClass('selected first');
            if (i == featureCt) control.addClass('last');
            controlDiv.append(control);
        }
        $(this).append(controlDiv);
        controlDiv.append('<a href="#" class="selector" id="stop">||</a>');
        controlDiv.append('<a href="#" class="selector" id="start" style="display: none;">&#9654;</a>');
    });
}
$("#fade").innerfade({
    speed: 2000,
    timeout: 5000,
    containerheight: 440,
    tracker: "switcher",
    trackerclass: "selected",
    repeat: 1
});    
$(".selector").click(function() {
    if (this.id == "stop" || this.id == "start") {
        return;
    }

    if($("#fade").data("timer")) {
        clearTimeout($("#fade").data("timer"));
        $("#fade").removeData("timer");
        $("#stop").hide();
        $("#start").show();
    }

    var id = Number(this.id.substr(1));
    $(".selector").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    $("#fade>div:visible").fadeOut(1);
    $("#fade>div.item" + id).fadeIn(1, function() {
        $('body').removeMatchedClasses({ pattern: /^slide/ });
        $('body').addClass('slide' + (id - 1));
    });

    var num = $("#fade").data("num_elements");
    if (id < num) {
        $("#fade").data("next", id);
    } else {
        $("#fade").data("next", 0);
    }
    return false;
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
    clearTimeout($("#fade").data("timer"));
    $("#fade").removeData("timer");
    $("#stop").hide();
    $("#start").show();
    return false;
});
$("#start").click(function() {
    $("#start").hide();
    $("#stop").show();
    $(".selector").removeClass("selected");
    $("#fade").innerfade({
        speed: 2000,
        timeout: 10000,
        containerheight: 440,
        tracker: "switcher",
        trackerclass: "selected"
    });
    var id = $("#fade").data("next");
    $("#s" + id).addClass("selected");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Without code is simply .... "too hard" 
We have to use firebug for try to understand something that, maybe, could be figured out with little snippet of code

Comment: @DonCallisto I added the relavant code. Sorry for the oversight!

Comment: My FF detects a problem here: $('body').removeMatchedClasses({ pattern: /^slide/ });

Answer (score 0):

The slider method is instantiated on line 37 of site.js. On line 81, I'm seeing the following error when clicking on each of the selectors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'removeMatchedClasses'
```

There is no function declaration for `removeMatchedClasses`. It simply does not exist.

What they're trying to do is remove any classes that match the regex `/^slide/` from the `body`.

My recommendation is to replace line 81 with the following:

```
$('body').removeClass(function(i, c) {
  return c.match(/^slide/).join(" ");
});
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: This seems to have improved the issue, as it allows me to switch slides sometimes, unlike before. I've noticed that the way they're doing the switching is by modifying the z-index of the slide, rather than setting `display:none;`. Also, another issue I noticed is that if I switch to a slide, the rotation stops (which is intended), but if I click play, the slides disappear. Thanks for your help!